# Aligning things horizontally and vertically with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I have just discovered 'Flexbox' and it looks like something that will really make my (CSS) life easier. Nevertheless, I can not figure out how to horizontally and vertically align something at the same time, which should be very easy with Flexbox. I have already tried the properties listed here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, but none of them seem to work. I am probably doing something wrong. Can anyone help me?

This is my code (Customized Bootstrap to only include things as buttons, typography etc.)

```css
   

 body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    body {
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background: #5e129f;
      /* Old browsers */
    }
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
    }
    .wrapper.inner {
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Flexbox test</title>
      <!-- Flexbox-->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexbox.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="wrapper inner">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae viverra nunc.
                  <br>Phasellus auctor enim sed tortor ultrices commodo.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn more</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Donate</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I want .wrapper to be aligned horizontally as well as vertically, so that I can make the final product look like this (do not notice the style difference):

http://prntscr.com/5tj5sl

Thanks in advance! Hopefully someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center `.wrapper.inner`, put

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

on `.wrapper`, not on `.wrapper.inner`.

To center the inner wrapper on the page, I gave `.wrapper` and `.container` a height of 100%.

```css
   

 body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    body {
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background: #5e129f;
      /* Old browsers */
    }
    .container {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Flexbox test</title>
      <!-- Flexbox-->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexbox.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="wrapper inner">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae viverra nunc.
                  <br>Phasellus auctor enim sed tortor ultrices commodo.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn more</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Donate</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```